# About using interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface, extending

would you please help me in using the interfaces? Here is m code:

```
export interface WidgetAccess {
widgets: BaseWidget[];
iswAValid: boolean;
}

export interface BaseWidget {
readonly extension: WidgetExtension;
isValid?:boolean;
areaId?: number;
}

export enum WidgetExtension {
Score = 'score',
Ranking = 'ranking'
}

export interface RankingWidgetAttributes {
rankingType?: RankingType;
demographicType?: RankingDemographicType;
demographicId?: number;
topicId?: number;
}

export interface RankingWidget extends BaseWidget {
extensionAttributes: RankingWidgetAttributes
}

if (dashboardConfiguration.widgets.filter(w=>{
        w.iswAValid =true;
        if(w.widgets.filter((wid)=>{
                wid.isValid = true;
                if(wid.extension === WidgetExtension.Score){
                                      if(wid.extension === WidgetExtension.Ranking){
                    if(this.IsInvalidValidRankingWidget(wid)){
                        wid.isValid = false;
                        return wid;
                    }
                }
        }).length > 0){
          return w;
        }
    }).length >0){
        results.set('widget', false);
        results.set('valid', false);
    }
```

I am receiving : Argument of type 'BaseWidget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RankingWidget'.
Property 'extensionAttributes' is missing in type 'BaseWidget' but required in type 'RankingWidget' for  this.IsInvalidValidRankingWidget(wid), Would you  please help me?

```
IsInvalidValidRankingWidget(widget : RankingWidget): boolean{
        if((widget.areaId === undefined || widget.areaId === null) 
        && (widget.extensionAttributes.topicId === undefined  ||  
        widget.extensionAttributes.topicId === null)
        ){
        return true;
         }
        return false;
 }
```

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code in the question to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now my IDE complains about `RankingType`, `RankingDemographicType`, `dashboardConfiguration`, `results` not being defined, along with `this` not being in any usable scope, among other things. So I'm kind of stuck. If you make it easy for others to play around with the code, you increase your likelihood of getting a usable answer.  If you do decide to edit this way and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.

Comment: What i can see and understand. IsInvalidValidRankingWIdget should check if wid is a invalidRanking widget. My guess is you are doing somesort of illegal casting and attribute calling inside there. Id reccomend you read about typeguards. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html I think this can help you to implement what you want. But without knowing what you do inside IsInvalidValidRankingWidget i cant say more.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoTaht, I put IsInvalidValidRankingWidget.

Comment: Yep seems like a casting issue. Change the WidgetType to BaseWidge and cast it into RankingWidget inside the IsInvalidValidRankingWidget

Comment: @MarkoTaht would you please help me in the code? I am very new.. I dont know how (Change the WidgetType to BaseWidge and cast it into RankingWidget inside the IsInvalidValidRankingWidget) but here  is a point! I have another functions which have the arg as base widget so i can not change my base widget itself.

Comment: @MarkoTaht thank you for this question, Can I ask you another question?

Comment: Is it related to the same topic or is it something new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i presume the error is in the method IsInvalidValidRankingWidget. I would rewrite it so

```
IsInvalidValidRankingWidget(widget : BaseWidget): boolean{
    const rankingWidget = widget as RankingWidget;
    if((rankingWidget .areaId === undefined || rankingWidget .areaId === null) 
    && (rankingWidget .extensionAttributes.topicId === undefined  ||  
    rankingWidget .extensionAttributes.topicId === null)
    ){
    return true;
     }
    return false;
}
```

This should fix the error i hope.